# To have the records of all the data without writing the segments again and again in the code while adding in the database

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

In a table I am having 292 records, for these 292 records I wrote 63 segments of parallel asynchronous in DynamoDB. If the records increases again I am writing segments in the code. Without writing the code like that to have added records to display, what is the solution. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable a DynamoDB Stream on your table, and connect a lambda function that is triggered by the stream to display newly added records.

Comment: Please help in detail to overcome this issue, it is necessary to me.

Comment: You can find a step by step walkthrough on triggering a lambda with a DynamoDB stream in the [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb-example.html).

Comment: By doing this, now I can have the data of full without adding code again and again.

Comment: My project is realestate, I have number of records in all cities in my country. If there is a house or place in a city is ready to sell, this record will enter and it will be automatically displayed in the results page while we are searching for sale properties, without writing the code again and again. If I add a record in the database it will be updated and will be shown in the results page according to the search. To maintain my database as dynamodb what are the things i have to do, please suggest me.

Comment: Please provide example script to display the data dynamically from the database. That means when I added a record to the dynamo database, without writing the segments again and again, I want to display the records of newly added. I am using nodejs.

Comment: Please provide the script.